# How can I resolve the following gradle dependency mismatch problem in Android Studio? The issue is mentioned below:

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

[image: Gradle Error]

> All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 17.1.0, 17.0.4, 17.0.2, 17.0.1, 16.2.2, 16.0.4, 16.0.3,
>   16.0.2, 16.0.1, 16.0.0. Examples include com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.0 and
>   com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.4 less... (Ctrl+F1)
>
> There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that
>   are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is
>   compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not
>   the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion.)

The Gradle dependencies are as follows:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.0'
implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.github.apl-devs:appintro:v4.2.3'
implementation 'com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.5'
```

}

I tried using the 'play-services-ads' dependency instead of the 'firebase-ads'. Also tried adding the 'firebase-iid' dependency, but for no luck. 
I am not sure if this is relevant but if I see the gradle console, I see this warning 'Warning:Failed to parse host www-proxy.idc.oracle.com'.
How to resolve the dependencies correctly?

Comment: This show the errors as warning but not effect the app.

Comment: @VishalSharma It doesn't seem to be causing an issue at present. But, I would like to not take a chance, since this is for a production application.

Comment: Please, [don't post your code/error messages as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4298200). Firstly we want to copy/paste it and secondly search engines are unable to index that information. So please make sure that any textual information is actually provided in text form.

Comment: @lucascaro You are right. Updated the question with text information of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem before. If you are already messing those versions, I will suggest you go through official's [Setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) again. There might have something needs to be upgraded.

Especially these 2 steps:

1.Check root `gradle` 's `gms` version.

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
  }
}
```

2.Update all dependencies in app's `gradle` to the latest, example:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
```

For the latest version : [Firebase Release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)

Comment: dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }